# Sending POST with https://www.hurl.it/ works but sending the same one with cURL in the commandline doesn't

Tags: post, curl

I'm integrating a payment service in a site that I'm building, and I need to send the following POST request to https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago

```
curl --sslv3 -X POST \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago' \
-d '{
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantSignature': '8A20806C19A5C1D4E25CF26A24F19265CD32F9DE',
    'Ds_Redsys_Url': 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago',
    'Ds_Merchant_Amount': 1000,
    'Ds_Merchant_ProductDescription': 'ZZSaas services',
    'Ds_Merchant_UrlOK': 'http://www.zzsaas.com/redsys/confirm',
    'Ds_Merchant_ConsumerLanguage': '001',
    'Ds_Merchant_Titular': 'Zikzakmedia SL',
    'Ds_Merchant_UrlKO': 'http://www.zzsaas.com/redsys/cancel',
    'Ds_Merchant_Currency': 978,
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantData': None,
    'Ds_Merchant_Order': '12345ISW',
    'Ds_Merchant_TransactionType': '0',
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantName': 'Zikzakmedia SL',
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode': '000000000',
    'Ds_Merchant_Terminal': 1,
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL': 'http://www.zikzakmedia.com',
}'
```

But that command returns this error:

```
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: services,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SL,
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 164
```

Changing **--sslv3 to --sslv2** I get:

```
curl: (4) OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: services,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SL,
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 164
```

Changing **--sslv3 to --tlsv1** I get this after 60 seconds of waiting:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sis-t.redsys.es:25443 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: services,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SL,
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 164
```

And **removing the --sslv3** I get this after 60 seconds of waiting:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sis-t.redsys.es:25443 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: services,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SL,
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 164
```

I also tried the following command

```
curl -v https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago
```

And I get

```
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sis-t.redsys.es:25443
```

Strangely, making that request with the webapp https://www.hurl.it/ returns the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

My curl version 7.39.0 works OK when not using any ssl/tls options and shows `SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / AES128-SHA`. Besides that, your data contains nested quotes and actually contains JSON data instead of www-form-urlencoded data; here's a corrected and optimized commandline:

```
curl \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago \
-d '{
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantSignature": "8A20806C19A5C1D4E25CF26A24F19265CD32F9DE",
    "Ds_Redsys_Url": "https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago",
    "Ds_Merchant_Amount": 1000,
    "Ds_Merchant_ProductDescription": "ZZSaas services",
    "Ds_Merchant_UrlOK": "http://www.zzsaas.com/redsys/confirm",
    "Ds_Merchant_ConsumerLanguage": "001",
    "Ds_Merchant_Titular": "Zikzakmedia SL",
    "Ds_Merchant_UrlKO": "http://www.zzsaas.com/redsys/cancel",
    "Ds_Merchant_Currency": 978,
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantData": None,
    "Ds_Merchant_Order": "12345ISW",
    "Ds_Merchant_TransactionType": "0",
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantName": "Zikzakmedia SL",
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode": "000000000",
    "Ds_Merchant_Terminal": 1,
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL": "http://www.zikzakmedia.com"
}'
```